# How can I stop water from seeping into my garage?

Tags: french-drain

Water is seeping through garage wall .People suggest dig and put French drain .I start to dig but can I put more concrete by the footer and support the wall instead of French drain?

---

The water is seeping from bottom to plastic isolation and to wooden frame inside garage.Its only like 3/4 of the wall ,about 12 feet .The seep starts from the corner.The inside concrete starts fall apart inside the garage.I send pictures.Thanks for help ,I don't have $ for professionals so I try to do it by myself.

Comment: A drain drains water. Concrete absorbs water. These typically are very different things. Can you give us a bit more details? Can you post a picture?

Comment: More concrete = larger mass to absorb water. Wall support is done by having a proper footer in the first place. Is the wall so deficient that it's out of plumb and buckling so that dumping a load of cement in there seems a good idea? Sounds like you've got other problems in that case.

Comment: Ok I will do the French drain and paint some liquid rubber on the wall and footer